# What's the meaning of the top number from plot_model of keras?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

What's the meaning of the top number "139873604363984" from plot_model of keras?

[image]

Comment: please add code of model, that will be more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topmost block in your diagram represents an implicit Keras input layer. The number itself is probably an internal Python id of the layer object. The appearance of this block is caused by a bug in Keras explained and fixed [in this pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11412#issue-223300903). As of Keras 2.3.1 this seems to be fixed, and implicit layers are no longer shown by default.

If you still use the old version of Keras, upgrading it by running `pip install Keras --upgrade` should get rid of this block.